# run-time error '3704' operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: vba, sql-server-2008, excel

Noob here. This vba code in excel is supposed to connect to sql 2008 using ADO, run the query and populate sheet1 in excel. Now, the heading error keeps popping up On this line
 " Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst".

```
Sub Code1()

Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SqlQuery As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Const stADO As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=NOPWDHERE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=StockControl;Data Source= PCSMIS01"

Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set WsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets(1)


SqlQuery = " SELECT * FROm dbo.Site "

Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

With cnt
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open stADO
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        Set rst = .Execute(SqlQuery)
End With

Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst

'With rst
'        .ActiveConnection = cnt
'        .Open SqlQuery
'        Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst
'        .Close
'End With

rst.Close
cnt.Close

Set rst = Nothing
Set cnt = Nothing

End Sub
```

I have also tried an alternative by using the piece of commented code to copy the data into the sheet.I have researched similar topics on the internet to the best of my ability, but i am more confused now. Please help.

Comment: Replace `Sheet1` by `WsSheet` and that should work! ;)

Comment: and in general: do not use the sa account for such queries. Don't paste the password for your sa account in a public forum ;)

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I have tried using wsSheet and the same error pops ups in the same place. The password is just for illustration purposes. Wanted the snippet to resemble the code as close possible.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `Sheet1` (it isn't referenced) by `WsSheet` :

```
Sub Code1()

Dim cnt As ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim SqlQuery As String

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Const stADO As String = "Provider=SQLOLEDB.1;Password=NOPWDHERE;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Initial Catalog=StockControl;Data Source= PCSMIS01"

Set wbBook = ActiveWorkbook
Set WsSheet = wbBook.Worksheets(1)


SqlQuery = " SELECT * FROm dbo.Site "

Set cnt = New ADODB.Connection
Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset

With cnt
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open stADO
        .CommandTimeout = 0
        Set rst = .Execute(SqlQuery)
End With

WsSheet.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst

'With rst
'        .ActiveConnection = cnt
'        .Open SqlQuery
'        Sheet1.Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rst
'        .Close
'End With
```